# How to select column name "startwith" in proc sql query in SAS

Tags: sql, select, dynamic, sas, proc-sql

I am looking a way to select all columns name that "startwith" a specific character. My data contains the same column name multiple time with a digit number at the end and I want the code to always select all the columns regardless the last digit numbers.

For example, if I have 3 kinds of apple in my column names, the dataset will contains the column: "apple_1", "apple_2" and "apple_3". Therefore, I want to select all columns that startwith "apple_" in a proc sql statement.

Thanks you

Answer (score 3):

In regular SAS code you can use `:` as a wildcard to create a variable list.  You normally cannot use variable lists in SQL code, but you can use them in dataset options.

```
proc sql ;
create table want as 
select *
from mydata(keep= id apple_: )
;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `like`:

```
proc sql;
    select t.*
    from t
    where col like 'apple%';
```

If you want the `_` character as well, you need to use the `ESCAPE` clause, because `_` is a wildcard character for `LIKE`:

```
proc sql;
    select t.*
    from t
    where col like 'apple$_%' escape '$';
```